# How to make ScrollView supports mouse scroll in UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I use a ScrollView in my UWP app. And it supports touch scroll, but not support mouse `wheel scroll and drag scroll`.

After some research, I find that by defining a `PointerWheelChanged` event, it maybe works.

XAML code:

```
 PointerWheelChanged="ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged"
```

C# code:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    scv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scv.HorizontalOffset - e.Delta);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

But I got some error message:

> PointerRoutedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Delta' 
>       and no accessible extension method 'Delta' accepting 
>       a first argument of type 'PointerRoutedEventArgs' could be found

How to solve it? Thanks!

I attached all the XAML and C# codes for your reference, anyone could test it in you VS.

I can see the horizontal scroll bar and drag it to move the buttons. I can use touch to drag the buttons moving. But I cannot use mouse wheel or drag the buttons by mouse.

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <ScrollViewer  
        Width="400" 
        Height="150" 
        PointerWheelChanged="ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged"
        HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Width="200">Data 1
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 2
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 3
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 4
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 5
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 6
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 7
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 8
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 9
                </Button>
                <Button Width="200">Data 10
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Rectangle  
        Width="200" 
        Height="135" 
        Canvas.Left="200" 
        Fill="Transparent" 
        Stroke="Red" 
        StrokeThickness="2"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ScrollViewer scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
            //scv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scv.HorizontalOffset - e.Delta);
            //e.Handled = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("wheel changed................");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.dll ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I add using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.dll; and got error: The type or namespace name 'dll' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input'   @o_weisman

Comment: The ScrollView generally works. You've got some specific problem either in your code or in your mouse drivers. I think that the question should be closed, as it isn't clear what is the problem and can't be answered.

Comment: @IvanIčin   I attach all the codes, you could try it by yourself and see what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that PointerRoutedEventArgs doesn't contain any member called Delta, so the error you are getting seems correct. Don't know where you got that code from.

Comment: @o_weisman  The C# code ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged is generated automatically (while the content of it is added by me) when I add PointerWheelChanged in XAML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use a ScrollView in my UWP app. And it supports touch scroll, but not support mouse wheel scroll and drag scroll.

UWP `ScrollViewer` allow you use mouse wheel to scroll the content. I test your code above and it works well. When use mouse wheel, please make cursor hover on `ScrollViewer`(above Rectangle will cover part of the `ScrollViewer`). If you just want to horizontal scroll, you need disable vertical scroll. And `drag scroll` behavior only works on the touch device.

```
<ScrollViewer
    Width="400"
    Height="150"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    >
```

Comment: "If you just want to horizontal scroll, you need disable vertical scroll." This sentence is the key for my issue! Thank you very much!